# Visual Studio/Resharper: Navigate to overriden method

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, inheritance, navigation, resharper

I have a base class `Base` and a class `Child` which inherits from this base class. The base class is `IDisposable`.

I have a call to the `Dispose` method of the `Child` class. Is there a way to navigate to the overridden implementation in `Child`?

```
Dim oChild as Child
oChild.Dispose()
```

When I press F12 while having the `Dispose()` method selected, I end up in `Base.Dispose()` instead of `Child.Dispose()`. Note that the declaration is as the `Child` type.

P.S.: I do have ReSharper so if anyone would have an easy solution with ReSharper, that would work too.

Edit (code example):

```
Public Class CBase
  Implements IDisposable

  Private disposedValue As Boolean ' To detect redundant calls

  ' IDisposable
  Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
    If Not Me.disposedValue Then
      If disposing Then
        ' Disposing etc.
      End If
    End If
    Me.disposedValue = True
  End Sub

  Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
    Dispose(True)
    GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
  End Sub

End Class

Public Class CChild
  Inherits CBase

  Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
    Try
      If disposing Then
        ' Dispose child specific
      End If
    Finally
      MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Try
  End Sub

End Class

Public Class CExample

  Public Sub ProvideExample()
    Dim oChild As New CChild
    oChild.Dispose() ' F12 on this leads me to CBase.Dispose
  End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: It would be helpful to add the code you have for your `Base` and `Child` classes. I have knocked up a simple C# example in VS2012 (with Resharper 8) and the F12 key takes me to the correct place. Did you make the `Dispose` method virtual in the Base class?

Comment: I've added a (VB) code example. I end up in the parameter-less Dispose method of CBase. Didn't notice this before, so the "problem" is something different. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any Code in der overridden method?

Because normally if you press F12 you are not getting up to the base. I think it's only if there is nothing else in the overridden method?

Comment: Yes, the method is overridden. Could be that my shortcuts or ReSharper are messed up but I've already reset VS and Resharper.

Comment: ...actually the method wasn't overridden. I was calling the parameter-less method from the `IDisposable` interface but expected to navigate to a `Disposable(Boolean)` one.